# Porqué no se muestra mi aplicación Spring Boot que desplegué en una instancia

Tags: spring-boot, spring, aws, instancias

Dentro de la instancia AWS que creé, subí mi aplicación Spring Boot y la ejecuté, por el puerto 8080 y la ruta '/api/easy-exam'

[image: captura de la instancia mostrando que corre la aplicación]

Pero pese a que aparece que ya está corriendo, al acceder por la IP pública

[image: IP de la instancia]

independientemente la ruta en la que la abra, no muestra siquiera la página de "Whitelabel Error Page" sino que muestra un timeout

[image: pestaña con timeout]

Si ejecuto la aplicación localmente si funciona correctamente

En la configuración de reglas las configuré así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora sólo se muestra el navegador lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que el problema es de configuración, pero exactamente que es lo que está mal

Answer (score 0):

Este error puede ocurrir cuando se intenta ejecutar una request [HTTPS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_seguro_de_transferencia_de_hipertexto) desde un cliente que no tiene HTTPS activa, el cliente va a encriptar la información cuando el servidor no espera que la información sea encriptada.

Por ejemplo puedes ver esa situación en la imagen que subiste en esta parte.

Dice "Not Secure" y la URL empieza con https

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]